# How to re enable submit button after data-disable-with in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, forms

Using `data-disable-with` attribute in `remote:true` form

```
<%= f.submit "Verify",'data-disable-with' => 'Verifying...' %>
```

After submitting button disabled and text changes to "**Verifying...**" but issue is that let say in case of error, errors show in form and submit button renable but the text not change . It stills remain "Verifying"

How can I show previous text in case of error?

Comment: You need to use `.js.erb` and update your button by that file, If you want to use it purely through rails.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<%= f.submit "Verify",'data-disable-with' => 'Verifying...', id: 'submit-button' %>
```

and in js

```
$(document).on('ajax:error', 'form-name', function (xhr, jqxhr) { 
    $("#submit-button").removeAttr('data-disable-with');
 });
```

replace the form-name with your form id or class

Comment: This entirely removes the disable-with attribute - it "works" but is likely not what is intended?!!